# WCF Service TargetInvocationException - Possible Cyclic Reference

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I need a little help with an Exception being thrown at my WCF service. The point is: I need to develop a WPF application and I've heard that to treat data WCF is the best choice so I used it only with basic knowledge and now I have this problem.

The point is, I have a Customer class, a Supplier class and an Order class. I have then two services: the first one has all methods to add, read and edit customers and suppliers from database. This service works perfectly fine. The second service has methods to add new orders, edit orders and read them from database, and this service has a problem.

The class Customer has a list of Suppliers (the suppliers from which the customer buys), the class Supplier has a list of Customers (the customers that buy from that supplier). The class order has a Customer, a Supplier and a list of Itens (and the itens are added to the database together with the order).

The method for adding an order works fine, however, once an order has been added, the method to list the orders throws the TargetInvocationException. I searched a lot on the internet and the best answer I've found is that it's possibly a "Ciclyc Reference".

The method to list the orders is inside the repository class and is simply:

```
public IQueryable<Order> ListOrders()
{
    return Context.Set<Order>().Include(x => x.Customer).Include(x => x.Supplier);
}
```

Where Context is the entity framework context. I tried to remove the includes and load the customer and supplier separately, but the result was the same exception.

Can someone please help me ? If I need to post more information just tell me. And sorry if this matter is trivial, I'm new to WPF and WCF so I'm still a little confused.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT** Exception below

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://SomeService.com/OrdersService.svc. This could be due to the
>   service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also
>   be due to an HTTP request context being
>
> aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See
>   server logs for more details.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at IOrdersService.ReturnOrders()    at
>   OrdersServiceClient.ReturnOrders()
>
> Inner Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected
>   error occurred on a receive.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
> Inner Exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size)    at
>   System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean
>   userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
>
> Inner Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)

Comment: Post the full exception and the wcf client code that is raising the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your data objects with the `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` attribute. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Hello HighCore, I've already tried that. I've heard about that attribute and I've marked my classes with it but the problem continues.

Comment: what kind of properties do you use in your objects? are they marked as [DataMember]? Enum types are not supported by the WCF DataContractSerializer

Comment: HighCore, there are no enum properties and there's nothing marked as [DataMember]. Is this [DataMember] necessary ? As I told, I'm totally new to WCF, so my classes only have the validation attributes. The only class with more code is the Item class which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Ahh... are you using the Entity Framework POCO entities? those cannot be transmitted over the wire if Lazy Loading is enabled (which is a property of the ObjectContext). if LazyLoading = true, you can use the objects only in the server side.

Comment: HighCore, POCO entities are the classes generated when we create the .edmx file ? I'm not working with .edmx, i'm working with Entity Framework Code First approach: I've created the classes myself and they map to the database using the Code First approach. Is this a problem ? I have a Context that inherits DbContext and a repository class with the methods to work with the context. Is this approach invalid when working with WCF ?

Comment: It should work as long as your Context is not working in lazy loading mode. take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontextoptions.lazyloadingenabled.aspx